# FullCalendar eventOverlap side by side only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

The below code is working good. eventDrag and Drop I can place anywhere inside the table.

But **I want to drag and drop the event only left and right side of the event.**

[image: picture]

I want to stop drag event from top and bottom of the other events. Only left and right side of the other events I want to drag and move the events.

Comment for further clarification. Thanks!

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ],
    header: {
      left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
 editable: true,
    resources: [{"id":"a","title":"Auditorium A"},{"id":"b","title":"Auditorium B"},
 {"id":"c","title":"Auditorium C"},
 {"id":"d","title":"Auditorium D","children":[{"id":"d1","title":"Room D1"},
 {"id":"d2","title":"Room D2"}]},
 {"id":"e","title":"Auditorium E"},
 {"id":"f","title":"Auditorium F"},
 {"id":"g","title":"Auditorium G"},
 {"id":"h","title":"Auditorium H"},
 {"id":"i","title":"Auditorium I"}],
 events: [{"resourceId":"d","title":"event 1","start":"2019-08-02","end":"2019-08-06"},
 {"resourceId":"c","title":"event 3","start":"2019-08-05","end":"2019-08-06"},
 {"resourceId":"f","title":"event 4","start":"2019-08-02","end":"2019-08-04"},
  {"resourceId":"g","title":"event 5","start":"2019-08-02","end":"2019-08-03"},
 {"resourceId":"b","title":"event 5","start":"2019-08-05T10:00:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-05T15:00:00+00:00"},
 {"resourceId":"e","title":"event 2","start":"2019-08-05T09:00:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-05T14:00:00+00:00"}]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/interaction/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-common/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but are you saying you want to make sure that a) events do not overlap each other, and b) you can only move the event within the same resource? We discussed point b) in your previous question. For point a) see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOverlap . If that's not what you mean, please give us further clarification of your intention.

Comment: @ADyson I want the event to drag and place left side and right side of the any events.

Comment: At the same time should be ignore in the place of top and bottom.

Comment: that's what you already said in the question. I asked you to clarify your requirement, not just repeat it :-). Anyway did you try the things I suggested for each point?

Comment: I think I explained correctly. Your example not helped me.

Comment: Well I didn't understand your explanation fully, so I disagree. If you don't want to try and clarify it, then I can't help you further, sorry. And I'm not seeing a rush of other people on this thread. It's up to you. I don't think I asked you for anything hard, just to try and explain yourself a little more precisely, then I can be certain what you want - that's all.

Comment: ok thank you. I will look forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it now, you want it to be impossible to place an event underneath another event within the same resource.

When an event is underneath another event, then it means the two events must (at least partly) occur at the same time. This is called *overlapping*.

You can prevent this in fullCalendar by setting

```
eventOverlap: false
```

(as per my original suggestion in the comments).

Here's a demo. It is now impossible, for example, to move "event 1" to be underneath (i.e overlapping) "event 3" within the "Auditorium C" resource.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    plugins: ['interaction', 'resourceTimeline'],
    header: {
      left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
    editable: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
    resources: [{
        "id": "a",
        "title": "Auditorium A"
      }, {
        "id": "b",
        "title": "Auditorium B"
      },
      {
        "id": "c",
        "title": "Auditorium C"
      },
      {
        "id": "d",
        "title": "Auditorium D",
        "children": [{
            "id": "d1",
            "title": "Room D1"
          },
          {
            "id": "d2",
            "title": "Room D2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "e",
        "title": "Auditorium E"
      },
      {
        "id": "f",
        "title": "Auditorium F"
      },
      {
        "id": "g",
        "title": "Auditorium G"
      },
      {
        "id": "h",
        "title": "Auditorium H"
      },
      {
        "id": "i",
        "title": "Auditorium I"
      }
    ],
    events: [{
        "resourceId": "d",
        "title": "event 1",
        "start": "2019-08-02",
        "end": "2019-08-06"
      },
      {
        "resourceId": "c",
        "title": "event 3",
        "start": "2019-08-05",
        "end": "2019-08-06"
      },
      {
        "resourceId": "f",
        "title": "event 4",
        "start": "2019-08-02",
        "end": "2019-08-04"
      },
      {
        "resourceId": "g",
        "title": "event 5",
        "start": "2019-08-02",
        "end": "2019-08-03"
      },
      {
        "resourceId": "b",
        "title": "event 5",
        "start": "2019-08-05T10:00:00+00:00",
        "end": "2019-08-05T15:00:00+00:00"
      },
      {
        "resourceId": "e",
        "title": "event 2",
        "start": "2019-08-05T09:00:00+00:00",
        "end": "2019-08-05T14:00:00+00:00"
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/interaction/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-common/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Yes. This what I expected correctly. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Ok, glad that helped. P.s. this is the same as my first suggestion in the comments, which you claimed you had tried and was not useful...did you actually try it the first time??

Comment: I tried but implemented wrongly. I am learning js not in depth in that. hopefully I get closer within a month.

Answer (score 2):

Quite Difficult To Understand, But I guess you want to drag only left and right side(from one time to another). not up to to down(from one resource to another).

For stop dragging to another resource you just need to add following option in your options of fullcalender

```
eventResourceEditable: false
```

---

**Example**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ],
    header: {
      left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
 editable: true,
   eventResourceEditable: false ,
    resources: [{"id":"a","title":"Auditorium A"},{"id":"b","title":"Auditorium B"},
 {"id":"c","title":"Auditorium C"},
 {"id":"d","title":"Auditorium D","children":[{"id":"d1","title":"Room D1"},
 {"id":"d2","title":"Room D2"}]},
 {"id":"e","title":"Auditorium E"},
 {"id":"f","title":"Auditorium F"},
 {"id":"g","title":"Auditorium G"},
 {"id":"h","title":"Auditorium H"},
 {"id":"i","title":"Auditorium I"}],
 events: [{"resourceId":"d","title":"event 1","start":"2019-08-02","end":"2019-08-06"},
 {"resourceId":"c","title":"event 3","start":"2019-08-05","end":"2019-08-06"},
 {"resourceId":"f","title":"event 4","start":"2019-08-02","end":"2019-08-04"},
  {"resourceId":"g","title":"event 5","start":"2019-08-02","end":"2019-08-03"},
 {"resourceId":"b","title":"event 5","start":"2019-08-05T10:00:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-05T15:00:00+00:00"},
 {"resourceId":"e","title":"event 2","start":"2019-08-05T09:00:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-05T14:00:00+00:00"}]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/interaction/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-common/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

I hope this is how you want

Comment: My expectation for example If I want to move the event 1 right side or left side of the event 3. How can I achieve that.

Comment: Can you understand my prob?

Comment: "I want to stop drag event from top and bottom of the other events. Only left and right side of the other events I want to drag and move the events." so side by side in same box??

Comment: event is placed as per data you gave like resource and date.

Comment: I can't able to drag event outside of the resource row. Can you understand my latest picture?